# How can I use gcc's -I command to add recursive folders

Tags: c, gcc, vim, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to use gcc's -I command and add all the paths to search path by giving a **root** directory?

I'm trying to use `:!gcc -E myfile.c` to view macro expansions, but `myfile.c` includes a whole bunch of other header files in different directories, and because I'm executing this command in vim, so I don't want to call a makefile, is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Apple's GCC (or Clang), then you can use the following approach (which appears to be an extension):

---

the parameter's suffix will need `/**`

```
-IMON_DIRECTORY/**
```

Now everything under `MON_DIRECTORY/` may be searched.

Obviously, this could hurt your build times and it can result in inclusion of the wrong file when files have the same name. So... use it sparingly!

Comment: `C:\Documents and Settings\nzwqv9\Desktop\New Folder\**` is my root folder, and `gcc -I "C:\Documents and Settings\nzwqv9\Desktop\New Folder\**" -E test.c` is still not finding the header file...

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce as well.

Comment: @shengy try `gcc "-IC:\Documents and Settings\nzwqv9\Desktop\New Folder\**" -E test.c` instead.

Comment: That looks like globbing, my guess is that it's a zsh feature, not a gcc one.

Comment: @AProgrammer i don't use recursive discovery - builds take long enough! this does work on my system - but i am beginning to think it may be an Apple-GCC extension.

Comment: @justin Still not working, I hate using gcc under windows.... it always messup with the slash or something else...

Comment: @shengy alright - i will assume this is an Apple-GCC extension, and update the answer. sorry about that.

Comment: @justin :) maybe it's just because I didn't use it the right way. I'll comment here as soon as I got the solution.

Answer (score 3):

gcc has [various ways](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/cpp/Invocation.html#Invocation) to control the [include search path](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/cpp/Search-Path.html#Search-Path), but I see nothing providing what you want.  Note that you can use [environment variables](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/cpp/Environment-Variables.html) for that, it could be more convenient for you than the alternatives.