# unable to get preprocessed source file or object file if I include header from a different directory

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, building

my folder/file structure:

```
testing
    folder
        head.h
    main.c

main.c
#include "head.h"
int main(){
foo(3);
return 1;
}

head.h
void foo(int x){
x = 5;
}
```

in cmd I go to "testing" folder and type in:

> gcc -c -lfolder main.c -o main.o

but that gets me an error:

> main.c:1:18: fatal error: head.h: No such file or directory
>   #include "head.h"

From what I understand, flag -ldir_name specifies that compiler should look inside of that folder for any #include files.
Can you please help me undersand what I am doing wrong. I also tried getting preporcessor's output:

> gcc -E -lfolder main.c -o main.i

again this should look for head.h in "folder", paste its content inside of main.c

Comment: Is that capital I or lower case L?

Comment: or you can try #include "folder/header.h"

Comment: The correct option for specifying include directories is a capital I (india), not a lowercase l (ell).

Comment: @StoryTeller thank you very much, script that I've been reading is using both capital I and lower case L, and I didn't notice that. That fixed the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use gcc's -I command to add recursive folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292707/how-can-i-use-gccs-i-command-to-add-recursive-folders)

Comment: -l (lowercase ell) is a linker option for linking a library... so is anybody going to post an answer?!?

Comment: @Matthias Take the chance. Write an answer, mentioning that you create one from knowhow in comments and give credits to the comment authors. If you can, add something of yourself, maybe a quote from gcc help or just better explanation. Offer to delete the answer yourself if any of the authors don't like it. With these conditions met you are likely to get some grudge-free rep. Most StackOverflow users appreciate or at least tolerate effort to shorten the list of unanswered questions.